# @Pattern regex allowing only : numbers & empty String & numbers beginning by 0

Tags: java, regex, spring, bean-validation

I'm using the @Pattern annotation on a String field in my Entity, with a regex allowing numbers or empty strings only, but I need to allow numbers beginning by 0 too.

This is the pattern I'm using now :

```
//..
@Pattern(message="Entrez un nombre" , regexp = "[+-]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|(0))([.,][0-9]+)?|(^$)")
private String BSCId;
//...
```

Thank you.

Comment: And this regex doesn't work for you? What is your question?

Comment: Try `regexp = "^(?:[+-]?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?)?$"`

Comment: Or, if a 0 or 0,00 are not allowed, `regexp = "^(?!0+(?:[.,]0+)?$)(?:[+-]?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?)?$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works great, thank you.

Comment: Which one works :)  ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The first one, I didn't try the second one because I need to allow 0 and 0.00 too :)

Comment: Nothing to do with JPA API. This is Bean Validation API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[+-]?(\d+)([,.]\d+)?)?$
```

This allows numbers to begin with 0, and also allows the string to be empty by making the whole string optional.

- `[+-]?(\d+)` match optional `+` or `-` and then match 1 to infinity digits
- `([,.]\d+)?` match `,` or `.` and then one to infinity digits. Make the whole fraction optional, so as integers could also be matched.
- `(?:...)?` make everything optional (so as empty string would match as per requirements), without creating a capture group.

Comment: It didn't work, but Wiktor already answered my question, thanks anyway.

Comment: Now, it is a copy of my suggestion. Could you at least explain why it should work?

Comment: @nicael I'm no expert, but I can't use `^(?:[+-]?(\d+)([,.]\d+)?)?$` in my @Pattern annotation

Comment: @Wiktor I didn't mean to copy your suggestion. There're not many nice variants here, and looks like we've got out variants crossed. Also, as you see yours works and mine doesn't.

Comment: @dwix: Because you have to double backslashes.

Comment: @nicael It worked with the double backslash, thanks.

Comment: Well then, thank you both. I'll mark this as answer then.